# Laravel Route protection for authenticated users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have couple of links similar to the below that I would like to protect by a condition that only logged-in users can access the specified views.

Here the route sample I would like to protect:

```
Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadHome'));
```

I would like to check if users are authenticated array

```
'before' => 'auth'
```

How can I modify the above route to include the before => auth ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('home', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadHome'));
```

Like that or you can protect a group of routes like so;

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

     Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadHome'));
     Route::get('another', array('as' => 'another', 'uses' => 'Controller@method'));
     .....

});
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Matt! You always save the day :)

Comment: when I try to visit any of the routes protected in the group and am not authenticated, it reroutes to route called login. can this be changed to different route?